# Why does map enumerable return value not return expected value

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I'm pretty familiar with the Ruby Enumerable module, or at least so I thought. Take the following code snippet:

```
names = [ "Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy" ]

new_empty_array = []

new_names_array = names.map do |name|
  new_empty_array << name
end

puts new_names_array.inspect
# prints [["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"]]
```

I know I'm not using `map` correctly, but I was teaching a lesson on Ruby enumerables and came across this example when a student was testing `map` out. The return value of the shovel (`<<`) operator is the array after an element has been added. Shouldn't the result instead be:

```
[["Donald"], ["Donald", "Daisy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"]]
```

It seems that the entire loop processes and the final return value of the shovel operator is processed? What gives?

Comment: Is `first_names` supposed to be `names`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `map`, in your case, is an array which consists of references to same array `new_empty_array` multiple times.  You are not creating three different arrays, but modifying the same array in the `map` block.

To get the output you are expecting, you need to do:

```
new_names_array = first_names.map do |name|
  (new_empty_array << name).dup
end
```

---

As a side note, you could use this code, which is more obvious than the code above, for the output you desire:

```
(1..first_names.size).map do |num|
  first_names.take(num)
end
#=> [["Donald"], ["Donald", "Daisy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"]]
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, the return value for each iteration is `new_empty_array ` and because the last iteration of the `.map` returns an array with 3 elements, what gets returned from the map is `new_empty_array` in it's last state 3 times

Comment: @AndrewKim  `new_empty_array` is reference to an array, and you return reference to it in map and hence, end up with 3 references to it as array - all 3 references point to same physical array which at the end of iteration has 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

```
new_names_array = first_names.map do |name|
  name
end
```

would give `["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"]`.

Each element of `first_names` returns a value to the new array created by `map` but instead you return for each element a new array, `new_empty_array`.

This object is `<<` three times and at the end has the three names, so 3 x 3 elements:

```
[new_empty_array, new_empty_array, new_empty_array] = [["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"], ["Donald", "Daisy", "Daffy"]]
```

Comment: @the Tin Man, thnx again for the edit, You must be investing a lot of time in correcting non english speaking people like me

Comment: May be you meant `non english writing people` ;-)